# jsp variables in java class

Tags: java, jsp

i have a jsp file which gets some details from the user like name and surname. I want to save the user's answers and use them in a java class to save them in a database.
Does anyone knows how can this happen?

Thanks
Al

Comment: Start learning JDBC and Servlets and come back if you have a more concrete question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/ and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: i know how to use JDBC, my problem is how to get the variables from jsp to the java file.

Comment: You seem to not know how to use Servlets. Collecting request parameters is covered in chapter 1 of a bit decent JSP/Servlet book/tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - submit them with a form. Then you can read them with `request.getParameter(..)`. Then use JDBC to store them in a database.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have made the form. do you mean that i can use the request.getParameter in java file and use the variables?

Answer (score 0):

The basic way of doing this is to import the class you'll be using, instantiate that class, and then pass the form variables to it using that class's methods.

Here's a quick example:

```
<%@page import="MyClass" %>

<%
MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();

//get the value of the submitted form element called "name"
String nameString = request.getParameter("name");

if(nameString != null && nameString.length() > 0)
    myClassInstance.setName(nameString);
%>
//the rest of the JSP would follow
```

As you say, you already know how to use JDBC, so it should be trivial to get that value into a database once it's in the Java class.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer it seems very useful, i will test it now.

Comment: Be careful. This answer exposes bad practices which may hurt in long term.

Comment: Anything in particular?  I would appreciate knowing what I've done wrong so that I won't make the same mistakes in the future.

Comment: i solve the problem with variables with the answer that @spookyjon reccomended. is it possible for data to be stored in the database in the same class which contains the setName() method? I've tried it but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @spookyjon Give this a read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202

Comment: Well, my mind has just been blown.  Thanks for the link.